# How records are being sorted while using join in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How records are being sorted while using join in psql?

In some cases seems like sorted by any one of the column
otherwise, seems like sorting by order in which it maches our query after **ON** . but not sure how its done. 
Especially while using right and left join
Simply, What is the nature of displaying records?

Comment: Is this what you are searching for ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @kenfire I'm asking about the sorting(records display order) nature of SQL while using JOIN queries.

Comment: In short: there is no order. If you want an order *in your results* you'll have to add an `order by` clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general there is no internal order to the records in a SQL table.  From the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html) on `ORDER BY`:

> After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. **If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order**. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.

If you want to have a certain order in your result set you need to specify one using `ORDER BY`.  For example, if you were joining two tables `A` and `B` you could use:

```
select
    a.col, a.col2, b.col3
from A a
inner join B b
    on a.col = b.col
order by
    a.col2      -- or replace with whatever column/logic you want to use
```

Even if there appears to be some order to your current query, you should not rely on it.  Adding more data, adding a column, or doing a vacuum all could cause this "order" to change.

Comment: Thank You. This is my answer too for my question, but for  "No internal order" - any citation about this in official Documentation?

Comment: @robincEPtion: note that this is not specific to Postgres. This is true for all relational database systems.